# Group data from a CSV file by field value

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which has duplicate value in first column . I want to collect all value of second column in a list  for one value of first column

```
column1 column2
a        54.2
s        78.5
k        89.62
a        77.2
a        65.56
```

I want to get like

```
print a  # [54.2,77.2,65.56]
print s  # [78.5]
print k  # [89.62]
```

Comment: I am very new in python , I have tried to read files line by line

Comment: And did you have any success with that? How far did you get? I suggest you look into the `csv` module and dictionaries.

Comment: For a newcomer, if the data really is that simple, string split might be easier than using the csv module.

Answer (score 10):

It seems fairly straightforward using python's [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

**data.csv**

```
a,54.2
s,78.5
k,89.62
a,77.2
a,65.56
```

**script.py**

```
import csv

result = {}

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in result:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[1]]

print result
```

**output**

```
{
    'a': ['54.2', '77.2', '65.56'], 
    's': ['78.5'], 
    'k': ['89.62']
}
```

---

As @Pete poined out, you can beautify it using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

**script.py**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)  # each entry of the dict is, by default, an empty list

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        result[row[0]].append(row[1])

print result
```

Comment: Even easier using `defaultdict`.

Comment: Indeed, but this is perhaps a bit more confusing for a newcomer.

Comment: Fair point, having to pass a function to the object and all that.

Comment: @Anto now i am in the middle of the problem . Now I have to pass the dictionary value in a function. But my function take list as a argument. Could you please help something

Comment: my function name percentile(N,.95), Where N is list. And i have now {'a': ['54.2', '77.2', '65.56'],'s': ['78.5'],'k': ['89.62']}. How can i pass ['54.2', '77.2', '65.56'] as a list named "a"

Comment: This is another problem and therefore should go in another question.

Comment: @BiswajitPain This is another problem and therefore should go in another question. In the meantime, feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9):

One way of doing this is by using pandas, populate a dataframe, use groupby and then apply list to all the groups:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['a','s','k','a','a'],'column2': 
[54.2,78.5,89.62,77.2,65.56]})
print(df.groupby('column1')['column2'].apply(list))
```

output:

```
column1
a    [54.2, 77.2, 65.56]
k                [89.62]
s                 [78.5]
Name: column2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach I tried Use groupby with apply and last convert Series to json by Series.to_json

Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['a','s','k','a','a'],'column2':[54.2,78.5,89.62,77.2,65.56]})
```

inputData

```
column1  column2
0       a    54.20
1       s    78.50
2       k    89.62
3       a    77.20
4       a    65.56
```

Solution:

```
jsonData = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].apply(list)
print(jsonData.to_json())
# if you want write a file into json
jsonData.to_json(r"D:/abc/def/xyz.json")
```

Desired output

```
{"a":[54.2,77.2,65.56],"k":[89.62],"s":[78.5]}
```