# Remove special characters when copying from .txt to list

Tags: python

I have a .txt file like this that I would like to store into a list:

> 'Plane 13','Paris','London',
>   'Plane 471','Berlin','Madrid',
>   ...
>   'Plane 34','Rome','Athens'

And I want to store its content consecutively, like this

> List_Planes = ['Plane 13','Paris','London','Plane 471','Berlin','Madrid',...,'Plane 34','Rome','Athens']

If I do

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    my_list = [line for line in f]
print my_list
```

I obtain

> ["'Plane 13','Paris','London',\n", "'Plane 471','Berlin','Madrid',\n", "...,\n", "'Plane 34','Rome','Athens'"]

So as the output is not what I want I must delete some characters (the double commas and the enters). However, if I add the lines

```
my_list.remove(',\n')
my_list.remove('"')
```

I obtain *ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list*

What am i doing wrong here? I thought that maybe there were problems with the " character between single upper commas, but if I remove the second line the error persist.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a csv file.

You can create your data like so:

```
import csv

data=[]
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, quotechar="'")
    for row in reader:
        data.extend(row)
```

Data is then:

```
>>> data
['Plane 13', 'Paris', 'London', 'Plane 471', 'Berlin', 'Madrid', 'Plane 34', 'Rome', 'Athens']
```

If you want each line of the file to be its own sublist (the more common situation) you can do:

```
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, quotechar="'")
    data=[row for row in reader]

>>> data
[['Plane 13', 'Paris', 'London'], ['Plane 471', 'Berlin', 'Madrid'], ['Plane 34', 'Rome', 'Athens']]
```

Or you could create a dict:

```
data={}
with open (fn, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, quotechar="'")
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]]=row[1:]

>>> data
{'Plane 471': ['Berlin', 'Madrid'], 'Plane 13': ['Paris', 'London'], 'Plane 34': ['Rome', 'Athens']}
```

If you really do just want to strip the `\n` from each string in that list, you can do:

```
>>> li=["'Plane 13','Paris','London',\n", "'Plane 471','Berlin','Madrid',\n", "...,\n", "'Plane 34','Rome','Athens'"]
>>> [e.rstrip('\n') for e in li]
["'Plane 13','Paris','London',", "'Plane 471','Berlin','Madrid',", '...,', "'Plane 34','Rome','Athens'"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. What I am searching is sth similar to your 1st option, however with every new line in the .txt file I get a _, '',_... I'd like to have all the elements consicutively, how to strip those characters?

Comment: Update your answer with the specific example and I'll see if I can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CSV builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25056367/1030960).

Basically:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar="'")
    for row in csvreader:
        # Do whatever you want with the row's elements
        print row
```