# How to group multiple csv columns in Python for Json Output?

Tags: python, json, csv

```
LoginName   EntryDate   Duration    Comments
===============================================
admin   2/27/2017   8   First Day Entry
admin   2/28/2017   8   Second Day Entry
admin   3/1/2017    8   Third Day Entry
admin   3/2/2017    8   Fourth Day Entry
admin   3/3/2017    8   Fifth Day Entry
randerson   2/27/2017   8   First Day Entry
randerson   2/28/2017   8   Second Day Entry
randerson   3/1/2017    8   Third Day Entry
randerson   3/2/2017    8   Fourth Day Entry
randerson   3/3/2017    8   Fifth Day Entry
tbenson 2/27/2017   8   First Day Entry
tbenson 2/28/2017   8   Second Day Entry
tbenson 3/1/2017    8   Third Day Entry
tbenson 3/2/2017    8   Fourth Day Entry
tbenson 3/3/2017    8   Fifth Day Entry
```

I am not able to group the above csv to json by grouping it based on the LoginName using Python.

Could someone shed some light on this, the other links in group by category for Python did not help me much on this situation. (Example: [Group data from a CSV file by field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055958/group-data-from-a-csv-file-by-field-value))

Comment: I'm not sure what that block of text is but it doesn't look like a CSV; the items are separated by a space? How can you tell one multi-word column entry from another?

Comment: Also, please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's much easier to help if you include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: consider https://pymotw.com/3/itertools/index.html#grouping-data