# Grouping data from a CSV file by field value according to argument

Tags: python, csv, argparse

I have a csv file shortened where I want to group the column by ticker meaning from this below:

```
Sector,Ticker,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,OpenInt
Technology,ibm,1/2/62,6.413,6.413,6.3378,6.3378,467056,0
Technology,ibm,1/3/62,6.3378,6.3963,6.3378,6.3963,350294,0
Technology,apk,1/4/62,6.3963,6.3963,6.3295,6.3295,314365,0
Technology,ibm,1/5/62,6.3211,6.3211,6.1958,6.2041,440112,0
Technology,apk,1/8/62,6.2041,6.2041,6.0373,6.087,655676,0
```

To this outputted after inputting a command line - outputting in a format:

```
python OLAP.py --input input.csv --groupby ticker

ticker,Open,  High, Low,   Close, Volume,
ibm,   6.413, 6.413,6.3378,6.3378,467056
       6.3378,6.3963,6.3378,6.3963,350294
apk,   6.3963,6.3963,6.3295,6.3295,314365
       6.2041,6.2041,6.0373,6.087,655676
```

For homework purposes we are not allowed to use any other imports other than CSV,OS,sys,argparse
I have been looking at this [Group data from a CSV file by field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055958/group-data-from-a-csv-file-by-field-value) to gain some insight and understanding of it and tried an implementation:

```
def main():
   format_dict = {}
   args = parse_args()
   with open(args.filename, "r") as open_file:
       readers = csv.DictReader(open_file, delimiter = ',')
   if args.group_by is not None:
           for row in readers:
               for index in range(len(row)):
                   if args.group_by == row[index]:
                       if row[index] in format_dict:
                           index_inc = index + 1
                           format_dict[row[index]].append(row[index_inc])
                       else:   
                           index_inc = index + 1
                           format_dict[row[index]] = [row[index_inc]]
       print(format_dict)
```

However I get an empty dictionary

I am currently just printing on console to see if I am successfully grouping it properly and correctly storing it. I am lost as to how to approach this problem without using pandas as I see pandas is quite powerful too but as it is a homework assignment we are forbidden to use it. If I could be given the right direction or an indication that my logic is wrong that would be wonderful

Comment: Where do you define format_dict?

Comment: oh sorry I defined format_dict = {}  inside def main(): Sorry I am new at posting in stack overflow so if I formatted the question incorrectly I apologise as it is my first time

Comment: Can you post the full function? One possible issue is you are overwriting the dictionary at each iteration but its impossible to tell atm

Comment: My def main() does not have much in it, i have edited it to add the whole function