# SQL output to a dictionary of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the following o/p of my SQL query (as a dataframe) to a dictionary of list:

```
Column A   Column B
M             N
M             O
```

I want the result in following format:

```
{M:[N,O]}
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: we do not know the format of the SQL result. You need to refine your question with more details

Comment: @mad_ It is a dataframe as shown in the input. Have made the edits

Comment: Do you use pandas for the SQL extraction? If so, please specify that this is a df

Comment: @Epic_Yarin_God Yes! Have made the edit. It is a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
a_dict = df.groupby('Column A', as_index=True)['Column B'].apply(list).to_dict()

print(a_dict)
{'M': ['N', 'O']}
```

Comment: This answer gets you going - SQL result / csv - all the same ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055958/group-data-from-a-csv-file-by-field-value

Comment: This solution is better because it doesn't require you to create lists.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
   tst = data.groupby("a", as_index =False).agg("|".join)
    tst['b'] = tst['b'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|"))
    a, b = tst['a'].tolist(), tst['b'].tolist()
    your_dict = dict(zip(a,b))
```

and vola

Please note that this is a round about way, and there is probably a better solution.